# Programmatic indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like a way to set values at specific indices and axes of a `ndarray` without using fancy indexing.

Say I have an array.  I can do:

```py
z = np.zeros((3,4,2,8))

# set z=9 at [1,2] in axis 0, and [0,1] in axis 2
z[[1,2],:,[0,1],:] = 9
```

But is there a function `set_value` that I could instead do something like:

```py
z.set_value(9, axis=(0,2), indices=[[1,2],[0,1]])
```

I don't think [`np.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) or [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) meet my need, unless I misunderstand how to use [`expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Comment: `[1,2]` and `[0,1]` are fancy indices.

Comment: Am I using the term incorrectly? I thought "fancy indexing" referred to any use of indexing within brackets, like `z[:,[0,2]]` or `z[...,3]` or etc

Comment: As far as I'm aware, fancy indexing is non-slice or mask indexing.

Comment: Remember that `[...] = ...` is just syntactic sugar for `.__setitem__(..., ...)`. It only becomes fancy when you try to do weird stuff with the first `...`, like passing in a list of integers

Comment: The official term is "advanced indexing": https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing. Masking is advanced as well, so basically everything that is not slicing or single-element extraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.moveaxis`:

```
z = np.zeros((3,4,2,8))
axes = [0,2]
indices = ([1,2],[0,1])
np.moveaxis(z,axes,range(len(axes)))[indices] = 9
```

This creates a view of `z` with the axes shuffled, such that they can be accessed as axes 0,1. The trick is that the data but not the layout of `z` are shared between the original array and this view. By writing to the view `z` will be modified as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can create such a function yourself:

```py
def set_value(arr, value, *, axis, indices):
    index = [slice(None)] * len(arr.shape)
    for a, i in zip(axis, indices):
        index[a] = i
    arr[tuple(index)] = value
```